# mapr streams with spark streaming compatability

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, mapr

Does mapr streams work with pyspark.I downloaded the necessary jars and tried testing the following example.
https://github.com/ihijazi/data-engineering/blob/master/Kafka-MapR-DB-HBase.py
plz advise what i am missing.

```
[mapr@ip-10-0-0-85 centos]$ /opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.1.0/bin/spark-
submit --jars /opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.1.0/jars/spark-streaming_2.10-
2.1.0.jar /home/mapr/kafka.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/mapr/kafka.py", line 7, in <module>
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import *;
ImportError: No module named kafka
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Issam Hijazi's findings that pyspark is not compiled to work with MapR Streams (since it doesn't use v09). However, he also reported that downloaded the latest build http://package.mapr.com/releases/ecosystem-5.x/redhat/mapr-spark-1.6.1.201612010646-1.noarch.rpm resolved the issue. Please see details: https://community.mapr.com/message/54864-re-mapr-streams-via-pyspark-exception?commentID=54864#comment-54864

Answer (score 0):

Get inside the spark folder

```
cd spark/python/pyspark/streaming
```

Search if u have kafka or kafka08 or kafka09 and change accordingly in your import statement in your code